# How can I time a shell command n times and get some execution time distribution?

Tags: monitoring, time, software-rec

I have a shell command that I would like to time (e.g., a `curl` query). I don't want to time it once, but instead many times, so that I can get an empirical distribution of the execution time. How can I do so?

I'm guessing that I could write some program any language to loop around the `time` program, but I was hoping for a more off-the-shelf solution.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
for f in `seq 10`
do
    time curl www.google.com
done
```

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for something a bit more advanced e.g. providing empirical distribution statistics such as mean and standard deviation.

Comment: You could pipe it into a file and do do some fancy greps and cuts and stuff?

Comment: Yes.  I was hoping for a more off-the-shelf solution since that seemed to me to be a quite common need, but perhaps it doesn't exist and indeed we have to code it ourselves :)